# What is the reverse of scan() in R?

Tags: r, file-io

I want to simply write a space-separated list of integers to a file in R. I can *read* a space-separated list *from* a file using `scan`, but is there function for doing the reverse? In other words, how can I write a vector of integers to a file in such a way that I can `scan` the file later to read the same vector back in?

I don't want anything fancy like `save` or `write.table`.

Comment: Does this help? http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Export-to-text-files

Comment: And I don't know, write might be simple enough too: http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/base/html/write.html

Comment: You should have put that as an answer. `write` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: See help pages for `sink`, `paste` and `cat`. But still, I don't really get the point...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`write` does the job:

```
x <- c(10.4, 5.6, 3.1, 6.4, 21.7)
write (x, "mydata") # writes space separated list
y <- scan("mydata")
x == y 

# returns TRUE TRUE ... TRUE
```

Comment: This is not actually (exclusively) a space separated list, it just looks that way because the default is to write out five columns and you happened to choose five numbers. Any additional components to x wrap to a new line in the file.

Comment: Actually, I should have said that any whitespace separation is fine. I just said that it has to be readable by `scan`. And the 5-column layout is actually quite convenient for manual sanity-checking. It means my editor doesn't choke trying to wrap the single super-long line.

Comment: @Fojtasek `write()` is just a wrapper for `cat()` and the result *is* white-space separated. `scan()` doesn't care about how many lines there are in the input so it is irrelevant how many are in the output. Both you solution and that of @Benoit are effectively equivalent.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson Yes, I know write() is a wrapper for cat(). I took a literal interpretation of the question's first sentence, which asks for a space separated file and not a whitespace separated one. I assumed there was some reason outside of scan() for not wanting newlines in the file.

Answer (score 10):

I think what you want is to supply a file agrument to `cat()`, which writes to the file without any extras.

```
> cat(1:20,file="foobar.txt")
> x <- scan("foobar.txt") 
Read 20 items
> x  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```